# Custom registration form and custom field

Tags: custom-field, user-meta, user-registration

I've created a custom registration form for my website with this code:

```
<?php
    /*
    Template Name: Registrazione-Custom
    */
    get_header(); ?>

<!-- Row for main content area -->

            <div id="content" class="left eight columns" role="main">

            <div class="post-box">

                            <?php get_template_part('/includes/content', 'page'); ?>     



                <div class="wrapper">   

        <?php

        $err = '';

        $success = '';



        global $wpdb, $PasswordHash, $current_user, $user_ID;

        if(isset($_POST['task']) && $_POST['task'] == 'register' ) {

            $pwd1 = $wpdb->escape(trim($_POST['pwd1']));

            $pwd2 = $wpdb->escape(trim($_POST['pwd2']));

            $first_name = $wpdb->escape(trim($_POST['first_name']));

            $last_name = $wpdb->escape(trim($_POST['last_name']));

            $email = $wpdb->escape(trim($_POST['email']));

            $username = $wpdb->escape(trim($_POST['username']));


            if( $email == "" || $pwd1 == "" || $pwd2 == "" || $username == "" || $first_name == "" || $last_name == "") {

                $err = 'Devi compilare tutti i campi obbligatori';

            } else if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {

                $err = 'Indirizzo email non valido.';

            } else if(email_exists($email) ) {

                $err = 'Indirizzo email gi&agrave registrato.';

            } else if($pwd1 <> $pwd2 ){

                $err = 'Le password non corrispondono.';        

            } else {



                $user_id = wp_insert_user( array ('first_name' => apply_filters('pre_user_first_name', $first_name), 'last_name' => apply_filters('pre_user_last_name', $last_name), 'user_pass' => apply_filters('pre_user_user_pass', $pwd1), 'user_login' => apply_filters('pre_user_user_login', $username), 'user_email' => apply_filters('pre_user_user_email', $email), 'role' => 'subscriber' ) );

                if( is_wp_error($user_id) ) {

                    $err = 'Errore in fase di registrazione, nome utente gi&agrave registrato';



                } else {

                    do_action('user_register', $user_id);



                $success = 'You\'re successfully register';

                echo '<script language="javascript">

                  top.location.href = "http://www.miosito.it/";

            </script>';

                // e inviamo una mail con la riuscita registazione

    mail ($email, "Registrazione Mio Sito", "Complimenti registrazione effettuata con successo. Ti ricordiamo i tuoi dati per l'accesso al sito username: $username, e password: $pwd1", "From: miosito@miosito.it");

                           // e inviamo una mail ad admin di registrazione nuovo utente

    mail ("miosito@miosito.it", "Registrazione Nuovo Utente Area Riservata", "Il nuovo utente $first_name $last_name con nome utente $username si è appena registrato all'area registrata del sito Alpe Adria Insurance Brokers", "From: miosito@miosito.it");



                     wp_set_current_user( $user_ID, $current_user );

                     do_action('set_current_user');

                     $redirect_to = site_url('www.google.it');

                     var_dump($redirect_to);



                     wp_safe_redirect($redirect_to);

                }



            }



        }

        ?>



            <!--display error/success message-->

        <div id="message">

            <?php 

                if(! empty($err) ) :

                    echo '<p class="error">'.$err.'</p>';

                endif;

            ?>



            <?php 

                if(! empty($success) ) :

                    echo '<p class="error">'.$success.'</p>';

                endif;

            ?>

        </div>



        <form method="post">

            <h3>Registrati al Portale Mio Sito</h3>

            <div class="customregistrazione">

            <label class="customregistrazione">Cognome*</label>

            <input type="text" value="" name="last_name" id="last_name" style="width: 50%;" />

            <label >Nome*</label>

            <input type="text" value="" name="first_name" id="first_name" style="width: 50%;" />

            <label>Email*</label>

            <input type="text" value="" name="email" id="email" style="width: 50%;" />

            <label>Username*</label>

            <input type="text" value="" name="username" id="username" style="width: 50%;" />

            <label>Password*</label>

            <input type="password" value="" name="pwd1" id="pwd1" style="width: 50%;" />

            <label>Reinserisci Password*</label>

            <input type="password" value="" name="pwd2" id="pwd2" style="width: 50%;" />

            </div> 

            <div class="alignleft"><p><?php if($sucess != "") { echo $sucess; } ?> <?php if($err != "") { echo $err; } ?></p></div>

            <div>Compilando il seguente form di registrazione il cliente accetta quanto previsto nel <a href="http://www.miosito.it/disclaimer-privacy/">disclaimer</a></div>

            <button type="submit" name="btnregister" class="button" >Registrati</button>

            <input type="hidden" name="task" value="register" />

        </form>



    </div>





                </div>



            </div><!-- End Content row -->



            <?php get_sidebar( 'right' ); ?>



    <?php get_footer(); ?>
```

I want to add some custom fields on my custom registration form. If I need to add the custom field on the default registration form, I know that I must use this code in functions.php:

```
 //Aggiunta del nuovo elemento al form di registrazione
    add_action('register_form','myplugin_register_form');

    function myplugin_register_form (){
        $hobby = ( isset( $_POST['hobby'] ) ) ? $_POST['hobby']: ''; //salvataggio del campo hobby
        ?>
        <p>
            <label for="hobby"><?php _e('Hobby principale','registrazione-utenti') ?><br />
                <input type="text" name="hobby" id="hobby" class="input" value="<?php echo esc_attr(stripslashes($hobby)); ?>" size="25" /></label>
        </p>
        <?php
    }

    // Validazione dei dati inseriti.
    add_filter('registration_errors', 'myplugin_registration_errors', 10, 3);
    function myplugin_registration_errors ($errors, $sanitized_user_login, $user_email) {

        if ( empty( $_POST['hobby'] ) ) // il campo hobby è obbligatorio e non può essere vuoto
            $errors->add( 'hobby_error', __('<strong>ERROR</strong>: Devi inserire un hobby principale','registrazione-utenti') );

        return $errors;

    }

    // Salvataggio dei dati
    add_action('user_register', 'myplugin_user_register');
    function myplugin_user_register ($user_id) {
        if ( isset( $_POST['hobby'] ) )
            update_user_meta($user_id, 'hobby', $_POST['hobby']);
    }


/*
 * Visualizzazione dei dati aggiuntivi nel back end
 * 
 * */


 add_action('show_user_profile','show_the_new_meta_values'); // hook usato quando un utente sta visualizzando il proprio profilo
 add_action('edit_user_profile','show_the_new_meta_values'); // hook usato quando un utente sta visualizzando il profilo di un altro utente

 function show_the_new_meta_values($user)
 {

    $hobby= get_user_meta($user->ID,'hobby', true);
    ?>
    <h3><?php _e('Informazioni aggiuntive','registrazione-utenti')?></h3>
        <table class="form-table">
            <tr>
                <th><label for="hobby"><?php _e('Hobby principale','registrazione-utenti') ?></label></th>
                <td><input type="text" name="hobby" id="hobby" value="<?php echo esc_attr($hobby); ?>" class="regular-text" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    <?php
 }



 //aggiornamento dei dati
add_action('personal_options_update', 'update_the_new_meta_values');
add_action('edit_user_profile_update', 'update_the_new_meta_values');

function update_the_new_meta_values($user_id)
{

    $new_value = $_POST['hobby'];

    update_user_meta($user_id,'hobby',$new_value); // dati aggiornati

    if ( get_user_meta($user_id,  'hobby', true ) != $new_value ) // controlla che i dati siano stati salavati nel db
    wp_die(__( 'Errore nel Database','registrazione-utenti' ) );
}
```

But, how do I add the custom field on my custom registration form?

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

You may try a very different approach which I just used recently. Try out the WordPress plugin Pie Register for that, it gives you an easy drag-and-drop interface for customising your registration form, adding custom fields of all sorts and the e-mails being sent and who is being activated. Hope this is what you need!

Comment: You can even use the custom fields created by the plugin anywhere in your template, though it is a bit tricky (you would best need PHPMyAdmin access to get the custom fields' names in order to use them).

Comment: Hello, and thank'e every one but i don't like to use a plugin. So how can i do?